# How can I get the number of customers that bought a product?

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, product-view

I am in product view page, and I want to display the number of customers that bought that particular product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know how many different customers bought an item, you can try this *(guest orders are summed as one customer)*:

```
# $product = Mage::registry('current_product');
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(450);
$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
    ->addFieldToFilter('sku', $product->getSku());
$orderIds = $orders->getColumnValues('order_id');

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $orderIds));

$countByDifferntCustomers = count(array_count_values(array_map(function($v) {
    return (is_null($v)) ? "?" : $v;
}, $collection->getColumnValues('customer_id'))));

if ($countByDifferntCustomers) {
    echo $countByDifferntCustomers . ' customers bought this product';
}
```

Comment: Thanks its working fine!!!
evry time you come to help me...Thanx @sv3n

Comment: I also make condition here, if that product is already brought by someone. If not, then dont show this text. How could i achieve this?

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$productId = 123; // enter your product ID here
$product = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addOrderedQty()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('id', $productId)
    ->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc')
    ->getFirstItem();

echo 'Total number of brought '.(int)$product->ordered_qty;
```

Let me know if it does not work for you.

Comment: No such option :(

Comment: I have edited my answer please check it.