# Show how many customers bought an item

Tags: magento-1.9, products, product-view

Is it possible to display on the product page how many customers purchased a certain item?

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How could i get that how this product is brought by this many customers?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181608/how-could-i-get-that-how-this-product-is-brought-by-this-many-customers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$product = Mage::registry('current_product');
$reports = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addOrderedQty()
    ->addIdFilter($product->getId())
    ->setOrder('ordered_qty', Zend_Db_Select::SQL_DESC);
$reports->getSelect()->limit(1);

echo $reports->getFirstItem()->getOrderedQty();
```

Comment: Thanx..but it shows me in floating value...eg. 3.0000 , how could i say that this much people buy this item.
actually, i want to display in frontend that, this many cusomers buy this products, thats it.

Comment: `echo 'Item has been sold ' . (int) $reports->getFirstItem()->getOrderedQty() . 'times.';` Note: this is just the number of total order count. Not for unique customers.

Comment: Customer count answered in your other question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181608/how-could-i-get-that-how-this-product-is-brought-by-this-many-customers

Comment: that is good.  if i want tot also get all this total order item grand total amount. like 5 product order and it's price is $10 per product then total amount should be $50.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these code at these location by padding product id in query

File Path:
**app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml**

```
<?php 
echo $productId = $_product->getId();
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM `sales_flat_order_item` WHERE `product_id` = $productId";
$rows = $connection->fetchOne($sql);
echo $rows;
?>
```

For more clarity take a look of below screen-shot

https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2626598/3811ea202d982ba52d13fd54b02dd57a